# Adding plugins to Qt5 after a first installation

Tags: qt, qt5

I managed to build/configure/install qt5 in my Ubuntu machine, but I did not set xcb support. Now I would like to add support for this platform. Is there any way to add just this plugin without having to reconfigure/recompile/install the whole qt5 stuff?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be sufficient to:

```
cd <your_qt_sources>/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb
<your_qt_install_dir>/bin/qmake
make -j<n>
```

<> means replace with values according to your system.
You'll be told after the build is finished where the plugin was placed. Place it then in:

```
<your_qt_install_dir>/plugins/platforms/
```

You'll need to satisfy the dependencies (several xcb libs).